# Next.js scss undefined mixin

Tags: sass, next.js

I have been building a project with React and using scss.

Now I want to migrate my scss files from my React app into Next.js

Here is a photo of my Next.js file structure

[image]

I am attempting to import my scss into the _app.js so its available to the entire app

Here is my _app.js

[image]

Here is a photo of my '../assets/img/scss/theme.scss' file

[image]

Now in the _app.js file the import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' if working for the app but when I add the import '../assets/img/scss/theme.scss' I get an error for undefined mixins. Am I missing some sort of bootstrap import?

Comment: I dont know anything about react, but you probably should compile your scss into css first

Comment: The issue is I imported all my scss from a react project I was working on which was in bootstrap 4.5. My Next.js has bootstrap 5. Bootstrap changed how they use the hover-focus mixin so I got undefined mixin in my Next.js app. I just downgraded to bootstrap 4.5 and everything worked